# How do i do an update statement where a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails 3, how do I update an attribute with a condition like:

```
Model.where("state == 'decline'").all.update_attribute(:state, 'deny')
```

This is definitely wrong, but I am drawing a blank on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 56):

[ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) supplies an `update_all` method.

```
Model.where(state: 'decline').update_all(state: 'deny')
```

Comment: Also be careful with the `.all` method, it makes the db call straight away and converts the collection to an array. It is very rarely useful as it makes the lazy-loading performance gains redundant.

Comment: I would be careful of doing this because `update_all` skips validations

Answer (score 8):

You can also chain `update_all` off a scope such as:

```
book.chapters.where(state: 'draft').update_all(state: 'unpublished')
```